# How I can Update the Self Hosted Bitnami Ghost CMS Node?

Tags: node.js, npm, content-management-system, bitnami, ghost-blog

Recently ghost dropped support for Node 14 and to upgrade it needs atleast 16/18. I tried running few commands and it says the node is already upgraded to latest version.o don't know why.

Please help me to upgrade node version in my Ghost CMS